# Can you map function arguments to properties automatically?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

```
var person = function(name,age){ // i want arguments[] = properties }
var p1 = new person("John",25);

p1.name // would print: John
```

Is there any way to map function arguments to properties automatically without having to explicitly say `this.name = name; this.age = age;` in the function body or anything that uses a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close with ES6:

```
function Foo(a, b, c) {
  Object.assign(this, {a, b, c});
}
```

This uses the object literal shorthand notation to create an object `{a: a, b: b, c: c}` and extend `this` with any properties present on that object.

It's not exactly what you want, in that it can't detect the parameter names, but is much shorter.

I would suggest that if you have enough arguments for this to be a maintenance concern, you may want to consider taking a single object argument (`Foo({first: 'foo', last: 'bar'})`) and simply using `Object.assign` (or `_.extend` or whatever is appropriate) rather than relying on parameter orders for many params.

Comment: Yes, because the fact that you can't get the param names from inside the function, it is impossible to automatically map the params to properties. This is the closest you can get